# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: (0 , _firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.db) is not a function

Tags: firebase, stripe-payments

I am trying to use the Stripe Extension on Firebase to handle payments for my project. But when I try to go to stripe's checkout I get this error Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: (0 , *firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5*_.db) is not a function.

This is the error

[image]

This is my ***Plans.js***

```
 const loadCheckout = async (priceId) => {
    const docRef = doc(db("customers", `${user?.uid}`));
    const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
    const addedRef = await addDoc(
      docSnap(collection(db, "checkout_sessions"), {
        price: priceId,
        success_url: window.location.origin,
        cancel_url: window.location.origin,
      })
    );
    const unsub = onSnapshot(addedRef, async (snap) => {
      const { error, sessionId } = snap.data();
      if (error) {
        // Show an error to your customer and
        // inspect your Cloud Function logs in the Firebase console
        alert(`An error occured: ${error.message}`);
      }

      if (sessionId) {
        // We have a session, let's redirect to Checkout
        // Init Stripe

        const stripe = await loadStripe(
          "PRIVATE_STRIPE_KEY"
        );
        stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId });
      }
    });
  };


  return (
    <div className="plans">
      {Object.entries(products).map(([productId, productData]) => {
        // Add some logic to check if the user's subscriptio is active
        return (
          <div className="plans-subscription">
            <div className="plans-info">
              <h5>{productData?.name}</h5>
              <h6>{productData?.description}</h6>
            </div>
            <button onClick={() => loadCheckout(productData?.prices?.priceId)}>
              Subscribe
            </button>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
```

I am trying to do the same thing as a video but they're using Firebase v8.
This is what they did

```
const loadCheckout = async (priceld) => {
   const docRef = await db
      .collection("custoners")
      .doc(user.uid)
      .collection("checkout_sessions")
      .add({
          price: priceld,
          success_url: window. location.origin,
          cancel_url: window. location. origin,
     }):

docRef.onSnapshot(async (snap) => {

const { error, sessionId } = snap.data():

if (error) (

// Show an error to your custoner and
// Inspect your Cloud Function logs in the Firebase console

alert(`An error occured: ${error.message}`);
      }

      if (sessionId) {
        // We have a session, let's redirect to Checkout
        // Init Stripe

        const stripe = await loadStripe(
          "PRIVATE_STRIPE_KEY"
        );
        stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId });
      }
    });
  };
```

Perhaps I did not correctly did the conversion to v9 ? Thank you for your help you all

Answer (score 0):

The `db` is not a function but you are trying to call it. Also, docSnap isn't one either. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
   const docRef = doc(db, "customers", `${user?.uid}`);
    const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
    const addedRef = await addDoc(collection(docRef, "checkout_sessions"), {
        price: priceId,
        success_url: window.location.origin,
        cancel_url: window.location.origin,
      })
    );
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did what you suggested but now I have this error :( Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Function addDoc() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field price in document customers/yjXvUaZaffXWir2ipOQv3Bk9qMd2/checkout_sessions/BKaYNxCzlp1JOUdvGagu)

Comment: It seems like your `priceId` variable is `undefined`. Can you try printing it out before you use it?

Comment: @hanzo yes you were right man, it's reading undefined. Do you know what can I do to fix this issue ? I would greatly appreciate it

Comment: You could try setting it to a static price ID (`price_xxx`) to test it. You can learn more here about how you can create/manage prices

https://stripe.com/docs/products-prices/manage-prices